# vb.net remove from 2d list based on 3 subitems

Tags: vb.net

I have two list of list of object's, based on three subitems of list1 if those subitems exists on an item of list2 then remove that from list2. I keep finding rows from list2 that exist in list1 and i am out of ideas.

```
Dim list1 As New List(Of List(Of Object))
Dim list2 As New List(Of List(Of Object))
Dim it As Integer = Nothing : Dim it2 As Integer = Nothing
While it < List1.count
    While it2 < list2.Count
        If list1(it).Item(0).ToString = list2(it2).Item(0).ToString And list1(it).Item(3).ToString = list2(it2).Item(3).ToString And list1(it).Item(6).ToString = list2(it2).Item(6).ToString Then
            list2.RemoveAt(it2)
        End If
        it2 += 1
    End While
    it += 1 : it2 = 0
End While
```

Comment: Will you be using a visual control for this like the listview? Or purely coded list object? This should be very easy to track and test if listview is used.

Comment: coded list object its all sql stuff i am trying to transfer.

Comment: I suggest you use a listview first to track your code, that way you'd know which ones were removed or which ones stayed. If you don't want to see the listview after it works, you can just set the Visible property to false.